# Template Driven approach to form and getting no action out of submit button Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular7

I am following along on a tutorial to learn angular, and I have stubbled across an issue that I cannot solve. I am trying to get the submit button on the form to just console.log just to validate that the submit button is working. When clicking on submit button I am getting no response from the console. Using Angular 7 CLI

register.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ValidateService} from '../../services/validate.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  fName: String;
  lName: String;
  username: String;
  email: String;
  password: String;

  constructor(private validateService: ValidateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(123);
    const user = {
      fname: this.fName,
      lname: this.lName,
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    };

    // Required Feilds
    if (!this.validateService.validateRegister(user.email)) {
      console.log('Please fill out everything!');
      return false;
    }

    // Validate Email
    if (!this.validateService.validateEmail(user.email)) {
      console.log('Please enter a valid Email');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

register.component.html file

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
              <h3>Angular 6 Template-Driven Form Validation</h3>
              <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="fName">First Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="fName"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lName"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Username</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"  />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" />
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add something like this to form tag `#exampleForm="ngForm"`

Comment: also button `type="submit"`

Comment: if you are not using angular validation  instead using server side validation then you can also just add `(click)="onSubmit()"` to buttton instead of adding `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` to form tag

Comment: should the console.log output to the terminal or would it output to the console inside of chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your button `type="submit"` and try to use formController and formGroups it would be much easier with validation and anything that would be needed in future